# Excel VBA to count records that have a certain number of elapsed seconds

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to report "Number of Elapsed Seconds" in these breaks: Less than 15 minutes, 15 to 19 min, 20 to 24 min, 25 to 29 min, 30 to 45 min, 45 to 60 min, and 60 min or more.

I have a field that shows elapsed seconds and I am able to get the breaks I want -- In Total -- by using the following formula:

=SUMPRODUCT((ABS(TestTable!$AF$2:$AF$50)>=0)*(ABS(TestTable!$AF$2:$AF$)<=899))

(where 'TestTable' is the sheet where the data is located and Col AF is where elapsed seconds is stored). The problem?

I need to cut each break down by another field. Also in 'TestTable' is a field with either PRODx or PRODz in it (it's Col H).

So I need to say "If Col H = PRODx, then count how many records are less than 15 min and put it in a certain cell ---THEN--- if Col H = PRODz then count how many records are less than 15 min and put that result in a different cell".

Anybody know a way to write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have excel 2007 or later, `COUNTIFS` should work out for you.
`=COUNIFS(H:H,AF:AF,"<900",H:H,"PRODx")` for less than 15 mins, and PRODx
`=COUNIFS(H:H,AF:AF,"<900",H:H,"PRODz")` for less than 15 mins, and PRODz
then for the ranges you expand the selection
`=COUNIFS(H:H,AF:AF,">=900",AF:AF,"<1200",H:H,"PRODx")` for 15-19 mins, and PRODx
`=COUNIFS(H:H,AF:AF,">=900",AF:AF,"<1200",H:H,"PRODz")` for 15-19 mins, and PRODz

keep repeating this for all the ranges of time/PRODs that you need

Comment: I'm using Excel 2010, so your solution worked well for me. Here's the actual code I used:     =COUNTIFS(TestTable!AF:AF,">=900",TestTable!AF:AF,"<=1199",TestTable!H:H,"PRODx")

Answer (score 0):

In cell A1, type:

```
=COUNT(IF(H:H="PRODx",IF(AF:AF="Less Than 15 Seconds",M1:M5)))
M is just another random column
```

In cell A2, type the same, but change PRODx to PRODz.

Make sure to enter all formulas as an array formula, by hitting CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER after typing, instead of just enter.

See this link for more: [Count If WIth Multiple Criteria](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/count-if.htm)

**EDIT**

If you must have a VBA solution, let me know. Otherwise, you don't need VBA. Also, if you are running Excel 2007 or above, you can use the CountIfs function, which will be cleaner and less resource intensive than the Array formula above.

Comment: In Col AF, it doesn't have the text that you mentioned -- it has the actual elapsed seconds. For example it might say "1296" or "602". How does that affect the formula? The part that is tripping me up the most is how to say "If a record that is PRODx -AND- has fewer than 900 seconds... blah blah blah".

Comment: Change AF:AF="Less Than 15 Seconds" to AF:AF < 900 (or whatever you number should be)